# ASP.Net Core 3.x - Scan and register all interface implementations in DI at once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, registration, scanning

How can I ask the default DI of ASP.NET Core 3.x to scan for implementations of specific interface and register all of them at once?

If not supported out of the box, what it the best way to achieve this with ASP.Net Core 3.x?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like ASP.NET Core 3.x supports automatic scan and register of dependencies, at least not out of the box.  However, I see there are quiet a few blogs discussing this topic.

https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-fast-and-automatic-dependency-injection-setup/

Comment: There is a github/nuget library that does the job. Read this: https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/

Comment: The default DI does not have this out of the box. You could take a look at [custom registration source in Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html).

Comment: You can do it using reflection. If all of your interface implementations are in the same assembly, you can get them and register with one line.